# find a best critial region

Tags: statistics

Let $x_1,x_2\ldots x_{10}$ be a random sample of size $10$ from a normal distribution $n(0,b^2)$. Find a best critical region of size $a=0.05$ for testing $b^2=1$ against  $H:b^2=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a random sample of size $n = 10$ from $\mathsf{N}(\mu, \sigma^2),$
then under $H_0: \sigma^2 = 1,$ the sample variance $S^2$ (a sufficient statistic)
has $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma_0^2} = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{1} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(df = n-1 = 9).$

A traditional test of $H_0$ against $H_a: \sigma^2 = 1$ is to reject for large values of $S^2.$
The quantile .95 of  $\mathsf{Chisq}(9)$ is $q^* = 16.919$ from printed tables
of the chi-squared distribution or from R statistical software as shown below. So
the critical region for this test at level $\alpha = 5\%$ is to reject for
$S^2 \ge q^*/9 = 1.889.$

```
qchisq(.95, 9)
## 16.91898
```

Because you have not shown an attempted solution, I have no idea what you have studied recently or how you
are expected to argue whether this critical region is "best," so I will
leave that discussion for you.